# Sharedpreference ifelse statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement, sharedpreferences

I'm using an if-else statement together with a sharedpreference, but it crashes.
My code:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Ferdig1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SharedPreferences skuule = getSharedPreferences("skule", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String skuleString = skuule.getString("skule", "");

            if (skuleString == "Vel eit alternativ..") {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Vel eit alternativ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (skuleString != "Vel eit alternativ..") {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```

When "skulestring" isn't equal to "Vel eit alternativ.." it works and it starts the new Activity. But when it is equal to "Vel eit alternativ..", the app crashes.

My ERROR log:

```
    10-09 16:31:53.543 15146-15146/com.heli.minvekeplan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.heli.minvekeplan, PID: 15146
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.heli.minvekeplan/com.heli.minvekeplan.SecondActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: Vel eit alternativ.... Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
 Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: Vel eit alternativ.... Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqh.zzjm(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
    at com.heli.minvekeplan.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:82)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Thank you for helping! :)

Comment: Read you logcat it clearly states that ***Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'***

Comment: See 'Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832 Also, the Exception is happening in `SecondActivity`, not `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First at all, use equals instead of == to compare Strings objects:

```
if (skuleString.equals("Vel eit alternativ..")) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Vel eit alternativ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

and the error looks like the sencondActivity when is calling a firebase path

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.heli.minvekeplan/com.heli.minvekeplan.SecondActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path:
```

Maybe you can show us this part. 
Regards!

Comment: After using ".equal" and cleaning my firebase it worked!

Answer (score 0):

There is a message in the exception stack trace, that clearly points out

```
Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: Vel eit alternativ.... Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
```

Hence, it might crash because your Firebase path contains invalid characters…